ReactJS: Sort and filter
I have the following:
const filteredItems = categorizedDatas2[key]?.items.filter(item => item.packingLocation === location);

if (filteredItems?.length) {
return (
<>{location}</>
)
}

How can I also sort filteredItems by packingLocation (A-Z)

You can sort with localeCompare.


const data = [
  {
    "packingLocation": "A"
  },
  {
    "packingLocation": "Z"
  },
  {
    "packingLocation": "B"
  },
  {
    "packingLocation": "D"
  },
  {
    "packingLocation": "C"
  }
];

// in your code, you'd do filteredItems.sort(...);
const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => a.packingLocation.localeCompare(b.packingLocation));

console.log(sorted);



Be aware that if you keep the current filter (item.packingLocation === location) then every object in the array will have the exact same location, so sorting won't do anything. You would need to either remove that filter or sort on a different key.
